# Spring Boot Configuration Properties not being set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I am trying to set up a clamav virus scanner in a Spring Boot environment.  So I want to set the host and port in a properties file, clamav.properties, located in my resources directory along with the application.properties file. it looks like this:

```
clamav.host=localhost
clamav.port=3310
clamav.timeout=1000
```

I have this class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("clamav.properties")
public class ClamAvClient {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClamAvClient.class);

@Value("${clamav.host}")
private String clamHost;

@Value("${clamav.port}")
private int clamPort;

@Value("${clamav.timeout}")
private int clamTimeout;

 public boolean ping() throws IOException {
     logger.debug("Host:"+clamHost+" Port:"+clamPort);
     blah.....
 }

private static byte[] asBytes(String s) {
    return s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
}   

public String getClamHost() {
    return clamHost;
}

public void setClamHost(String clamHost) {
    this.clamHost = clamHost;
}

public int getClamPort() {
    return clamPort;
}

public void setClamPort(int clamPort) {
    this.clamPort = clamPort;
}

public int getClamTimeout() {
    return clamTimeout;
}

public void setClamTimeout(int clamTimeout) {
    this.clamTimeout = clamTimeout;
}

}
```

It's not connecting and in the logs I get this:

```
2017-09-23 20:39:45.947 DEBUG 28857 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] xxx.ClamAvClient  : Host:null Port:0
```

So those values are clearly not getting set.  What am I doing wrong?  I am using the managed version of spring-boot-starter-web,  which my Eclipse is saying is 1.4.3-RELEASE

Any Ideas?

Comment: and how are you using ping? are you using `@Autowired` version or something like `new ClamAvClient().ping()` ?

Comment: DOH!!!  I am using new ClamAvClient()  That's probably the problem.

Comment: yeah, you should use autowired version with `applicationContext.getBean();` or `@Autowired` annotation. Just tested your code you provided and it works fine

Comment: Using @ConfigurationProperties("clamav"), refer to http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-configuration-properties-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `@ConfigurationProperties` to map group of properties to a Class  using Configuration Processor.

Using `@Value` inside `@ConfigurationProperties` doesn`t look right.

All you need to map your properties to the class is :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="clamav")
public class ClamAvClient {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClamAvClient.class);


private String host;


private int port;


private int timeout;

//getters and setters

}
```

`prefix ="clamav"` matches your prefixes in the properties file.

`host,port,timeout` matches the properties of the class.

Comment: I had to add the properties from clamav.properties to the application.properties,  but then it worked.

Comment: you can still separate it using @PropertySource to load your external properties

Comment: Thanks buddy, didn't come across this issue so far but got a new approach to read values :) GB